# What is different between select with aggregate and without it in speed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, aggregation

I have two SQL queries.

First query:

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SELECT dateadd(HH, datediff(HH, 0, time_Stamp), 0) as Time1
      ,[Field1]
      ,[Field2]
      ,[Field3]
      ,[Field4]
      ,[Field5]
      ,[Field6]
      ,[Field7]
FROM [dbo].[TableT001]
```

and second query:

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
Select dateadd(HH, datediff(HH, 0, time_Stamp), 0) as Time1
,Min(cast(Field1 as bigint)) 
,Min(cast(Field2 as bigint)) 
,CAST(Avg(Field3) as float) 
,CAST(Avg(Field4) as float) 
,CAST(Avg(Field5) as float) 
,CAST(Avg(Field6) as float) 
,CAST(Avg(Field7) as float) 
from TableT001 
Group by dateadd(HH, datediff(HH, 0, time_Stamp), 0)  
order by Time1
```

The first query executes in 30 seconds, and the second executes in 2 seconds!

While two queries read the same data from `TableT001` (about 1450000 rows), what is the cause of difference in speed?

**Edit**:

- The first query execution plan:

  [the first query execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU9H0.png)
- The second query execution plan:

  [the second query execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elw4k.png)

Comment: You should start by examining the `EXPLAIN` plans for both queries.  My guess is that there is some quirk at work here.  I would have also expected the first query to outperform the second.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You need to look at the execution plan and the output from `set statistics io, time on`

Comment: I guess, the first query sends a lot amount of data to the client, and this time is calculated in the query's duration. You can try in SSMS  go to Tools >> Options >> Query Results > SQL Server >> Results to Grid >> Discard Results After Query Execution and compare the time again

Comment: I try in Discard Results After Query Execution and now the first query executes in 16s and the second query about 2s. the first query return 1456463 rows and the second query returns 48586 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, aggregation is much slower than not aggregating.  However, moving the final result set out of the database also takes time.

The time spent returning 1,450,000 rows is clearly much greater than returning 24 rows.  I would speculate that this accounts for much of the difference in your case.  In fact, it probably accounts for *more* of the difference, because the aggregation should be slower.

Aggregation can make use of indexes on the tables, so your database might also have indexes that optimize the aggregation.

Comment: Is there any way to improve returning time? This problem has slowed down my application

Comment: Not try to return 1450000 records to the client?

Comment: at the end must be returned to client

Comment: @mahdi Get a faster network connection. 1.4m rows is 1.4m rows, whichever way you look at it

Comment: @mahdi, the time to process the result set depends on your network bandwidth and latency plus client processing and rendering. So faster network and faster client compute resources may help. Your are ultimately limited by infrastructure resources.

Comment: @Charlieface Of course, at the moment I have run these queries on the server and I am facing this time difference

Comment: Even just passing them through via Shared Memory on the same server will take time

Comment: @DanGuzman Of course, at the moment I have run these queries on the server and I am facing this time difference. I have not yet entered the network phase

Comment: @mahdi, even on the server, the same considerations apply for compute (CPU, memory). Furthermore, memory needs to be configured such that SQL Server, application, and OS play nicely together.